# How read value from URL including special characters?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my URL:http://localhost/category.php?url_key=special-category

I'm using `$_GET['url_key']` to get value from url.
Here is my problem, I want to execute query using `$_GET['url_key']` like 
`select *from tablename where url_key=$_GET['url_key']`.
After executing this query I'm getting error like Unknown column `Sample`.

Comment: It's too early in the morning to go over the many, many reasons why building queries by directly getting params from `$_GET` is a bad idea. With that being said, do some debugging, see what the actual query is. Echo it out or something.

Comment: check your query with `select *from tablename where url_key='".$_GET['url_key']."'`

Comment: @Andrew        while echo this this query  `select *from tablename where url_key=$_GET['url_key']` i'm getting that value,at the time of execution getting error unknown column.

Comment: So, if you're echoing `select *from tablename where url_key=$_GET['url_key']` you're getting exactly that, as in : `select *from tablename where url_key=$_GET['url_key']`. Correct? If that's the case, you're using single quotes `'` to envelope your query. Use double quotes `"` so you can get the variable values inside the query.

Comment: Is it's exactly "select *from" then "*from" should raise an error already...? But, tbh, you should escape it properly! Does "url_key" exist in your table? Or perhaps you are trying to read a field that does not exist?

Comment: if it is `select *from tablename where url_key='value'` then there is no problem,insted of that it is trying to execute `select *from tablename where url_key=value`

Comment: @Raphioly     `url_key` exists in my table

Comment: Try query like select * from tablename where url_key=$_GET['url_key']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all,finally got answer.
Here is the solution:
 `"select *from tablename where url_key='$url_key'"`

where `$url_key=sample-category`.